# How can I have a header('Location: ') in the same page as a csv file creation and output or create this csv file in an html based page?

Tags: php, html, csv, output

My app collects data using a series of forms, then this data is sent and processed using external API's. You can think of the structure as `form>processingForm.php>form2>processingForm2.php ...`

After all the info needed has been collected and the app is located at the last processing/sending page I faced an issue. Since there can't be any data output before a `header('Location: ')` I found myself trapped forever in that processing, htmless page with the csv being correctly downloaded. So I had my file but at the price of not being able to continue the process.

I thought about storing the values I needed to write onto the csv inside `$_SESSION` in order to retrieve them at the last page of the project, so it would not interfere with other outputs, but when I tried for the first time I saw that the page's html did not appear. This was of course produced due to php being loaded first, so the csv would be created and the page left completely blank.

How can I solve this issue? I want my csv file as well as any html at least as a last page. I would redirect directly to the start again and forget about that last page, but I also can't. The only thing I know would work is leaving that empty page even without a mere button to go back to the start. I guess there must be some kind of workaround to this.

I've also tried printing the last page using php -> Same thing happened since I was outputing the page as a whole. I have error reporting enabled.

This is that final page I've been talking about but once again it's not necessary, a way to simply redirect after the csv has been downloaded would be fine too.

```php
<?php 
session_start(); 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (!isset($_SESSION['logged']) || empty($_SESSION['logged']) || $_SESSION['logged'] != 1) {
    header('Location: url');
}



$arrayCsv = $_SESSION['arrayCsv'];

$filename = $_SESSION['companyName'];
$filename = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $filename)); 
$filename = $filename.'.csv';

header('Content-Type: application/csv'); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 


$fp = fopen("php://output", 'w');
$delimiter = ',';
$enclosure = '"';
$escape_char = "\\";


foreach ($arrayCsv as $customerCsv) {
    
    fputcsv($fp, $customerCsv, $delimiter, $enclosure, $escape_char);
}


fclose($fp);
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Fin</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/homeStyleSheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--NAVBAR-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.php"><img id="ubunetLogo" src="../img/logo-color.svg"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../index.php">Inicio<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./createContact.php">Crear<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Actualizar<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Eliminar<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!--BODY-->
    <div id="finalPageContainer">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="../pages/createContact.php"></a>
            <p  id="finalPageP">Todos los datos se han insertado con éxito. Volver a crear contacto.</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <footer id="sticky-footer2" class="py-4">
        <div class="container text-center">
          <small>Copyright &copy; Ubunet</small>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can not respond to _one_ request with two different resources at the same time. If you want to show an HTML page after your last step, _and_ have the CSV downloaded - then you will have to let the former trigger the latter. You need a separate URL that can be requested to download your CSV, and “trigger” this from your HTML page, for example via a meta refresh to that URL, or by assigning it to `location.href` via Javascript.

Comment: Thank you again! You are helping me quite a lot. I don't really understand how to do what you propose so I'm gonna search for more info and let you know how it went

Comment: That was great, thank you @CBroe. In the end I did not manage to store the csv file in the server so I ended up reworking the app a bit, but after seeing this issue I really thought everything was lost. I will be posting what I did as the answer but I will delete it if you'd like to post an answer of your own.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer, it’ll probably be a bit more specific to your project, than my general comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cBroe suggested in the comments, I was trying to obtain two different resources in one request. Those resources being:

1. The csv file.
2. The HTML/New page

This is not possible, so in order to trick the app a little bit I created a link in the final page that takes you to the same page with a variable to discern wether to download the csv or just show the view. This way the body now looks like this:

```php
<!--BODY-->
    <button id="finalPageContainer" onclick="location.href='http://10.200.210.61/index.php'" type="button">Todos los datos se han insertado correctamente. ¡Volver a inicio!</button>

    <div id="finalPageContainer2">
        <a id="getCsvLink" href="http://10.200.210.61/views/finalPage.php?getCsv=1">Obtener CSV</a>
    </div>


    <footer id="sticky-footer2" class="py-4">
        <div class="container text-center">
          <small>Copyright &copy; Ubunet</small>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

This is also possible by adding this code at the beginning:

```php
session_start(); 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (!isset($_SESSION['logged']) || empty($_SESSION['logged']) || $_SESSION['logged'] != 1) {
    header('Location: '.$url);
}


if (isset($_GET['getCsv']) && $_GET['getCsv'] == 1) {
    $arrayCsv = $_SESSION['arrayCsv'];

    $filename = $_SESSION['companyName'];
    $filename = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $filename)); 
    $filename = $filename.'.csv';

    header('Content-Type: application/csv'); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 


    $fp = fopen("php://output", 'w');
    $delimiter = ',';
    $enclosure = '"';
    $escape_char = "\\";


    foreach ($arrayCsv as $customerCsv) {
        fputcsv($fp, $customerCsv, $delimiter, $enclosure, $escape_char);
    }


    fclose($fp);

    die();
}
```

The `die()` at the end is very important for it prevents the html from leaking to the csv file, so the only thing written onto it are the values I need.